# Manual css-modules with attributes to distinguish components

Tags: javascript, css, less, css-modules

## The scenario

I am trying to distinguish between components by using a custom attribute `component`. Example:

```
<div component="A">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Styling this is easy:

```
[component=A] span {
  color: red;
}
```

## The problem

Here is the tricky part. To be sure that components do not create side-effects, it should not style anything that is in a subcomponent:

```
<div component="A">
  <span>This should be styled by component=A styles</span>
  <div component="B">
    <span>This should NOT be styled by component=A styles</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Complete example

This is a [**bare example**](https://codepen.io/alp82/pen/JXpNPr). It defines the structure and styling for the outer component.

HTML

```
<div component="A">
  <span>Component A (red)</span>
  <div>
    <span>Component A (red)</span>
  </div>
  <div component="B">
    <span>Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    <div>
      <span>Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    </div>
    <div component="A">
      <span>Subcomponent A (red)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Component A (red)</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
[component=A] :not([component]) span {
  color: red;
}
```

## The first approach

Here is a [**first naive approach**](https://codepen.io/alp82/pen/BKYzOw).

It has several logical problems, but i think you get the idea what i am trying to do.

My feeling is that this is not possible with pure css. But before writing custom Javascript, i wanted to ask you if i am missing something or overthinking the problem.

Comment: It's coming - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-containment-3/#contain-property

Comment: Something like this (kind of redondant) is ok for you ? : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPXmyQ

Comment: @Paulie_D: wow, that's completly new to me. thanks

Comment: @VincentG: that's too specific. i don't want to explicitely name subcomponents and reset styles

Comment: You should consider moving to BEM to get rid of these problems. http://getbem.com

Comment: Remember that CSS attribute selectors are slower than class selectors.

Comment: Yes, i guess BEM or similar style guides are the way to go then.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reliable expected structure of your components, why don't you use the  `>` [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)?

```css
[component="A"] > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div component="A">
  <span>This should be styled by component=A styles</span>
  <div component="B">
    <span>This should NOT be styled by component=A styles</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to nest components that inherit the parent styles if no componenet is specified, an approach like this might work - based on your initial approach. For this to work you need to specify styles for component B as well as A.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGyeMg

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

[component=A] > span,
[component=A] div:not([component]) > span {
  color: red;
}

[component=B] > span,
[component=B] div:not([component]) > span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div component="A">
  <span>Component A (red)</span>
  <div>
    <span>Component A (red)</span>
  </div>
  <div component="B">
    <span>Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    <div>
      <span>Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    </div>
    <div component="A">
      <span>Subcomponent A (red)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Component A (red)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly this is not an option. Please take a look at my example: https://codepen.io/alp82/pen/JXpNPr

Comment: I see. Are you able to add the `component` attribute for all components, whether appearing as a root or sub item? And if not, do you know the maximum level of nesting?

Comment: Nesting levels are arbitrary. Putting the `component` to all parent selectors would be impractical.

Comment: Edited. There may be some more complex nesting combinations where it doesn't work, but if you really don't want to specify the component on each one I'm not sure how it could be done. I think the complexity of the necessary CSS would end up outweighing the impracticality of specifying it on each one.

Comment: Your edit still styles sub components and resets styles from parent components. I want to avoid that. I guess you are right with your concerns and that i need to choose another path to get what i want (bem, suit, javascript, etc.)

Comment: I would just put the component attribute on every component and use the direct child selector as per my original answer. That would do exactly what you want I believe without any style cascading. I also think having the component attribute on each component feels more modular and separated.

Comment: I'd prefer not to limit components to only one level of nesting.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough, but you could nest as much as you like if you specified each component attribute: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKYwxy

Comment: Yes, i get that. But if my component has multiple levels in itself, that approach won't work anymore. Here is an example for such a component: https://codepen.io/alp82/pen/pyaOoQ

Answer (score 1):

You may follow the [BEM convention](http://getbem.com):

```css
.a {
  /* component A */
}
.a__red {
  /* element red child of component A */
  color: red;
}

.b {
  /* component B */
}
.b__black {
  /* element black child of component B */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span class="a__red">Component A (red)</span>
  <div>
    <span class="a__red">Component A (red)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <span class="b__black">Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    <div>
      <span class="b__black">Subcomponent B (black)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
      <span class="a__red">Subcomponent A (red)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="a__red">Component A (red)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at these,

i am not experienced like you but maybe it will help you.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/2/

HTML:

```
<div component="A">
 <span>This should be styled by component=A styles</span>
 <div component="B">
   <span>This should NOT be styled by component=A styles</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[component=A] span{
  color: red;
}

[component=B]  span{
  color: BLUE;
}
```